# Automatically connect signals to custom Django model fields

Tags: django, model, signals, custom-fields, django-signals

I've created a custom image field for Django that automatically creates thumbnails and does some other stuff.

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile

class ImageWithThumbsFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Now I would like to *automatically* connect a post_delete signal whenever such a field is defined in a model. I know how to connect a post_delete signal manually when the model is defined. But i there a way to do that automatically whenever the custom field is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the `contribute_to_class()` method:

```
class ImageWithThumbsFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    ...
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
        super(ImageWithThumbsFieldFile, self).contribute_to_class(
                                                   cls, name, **kwargs)
        post_delete.connect(on_delete_callback, sender=cls)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thought there must be something simple like that, but couldn't find it.